# Red bird reverse proxy issue with meteor hostname+paths

Tags: node.js, meteor, reverse-proxy, redbird

I use [Red bird reverse proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redbird) for my meteor apps and my request are redirecly correctly when i use the below configuration i.e subdomain config

```
var proxy = require('redbird')({port: 80});

proxy.register("app1.example.com", "http://127.0.0.1:3000");
proxy.register("app2.example.com", "http://127.0.0.1:4000");
```

but when i use domain/ip + paths like in the below configuration

```
var proxy = require('redbird')({port: 80});

proxy.register("http://127.0.0.1/a", "http://127.0.0.1:3000");
proxy.register("http://127.0.0.1/b", "http://127.0.0.1:4000");
```

i get the error "no valid route found for given source". below is the screenshot from browser

[screenshot from browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNRIB.png)

Please let me know what i am doing wrong

Comment: I assume you wanted to route both localhost and example.com to the same local server. Did I understand well? Maybe you should send an issue about this. https://github.com/OptimalBits/redbird/issues

Comment: I found the issue here: https://github.com/OptimalBits/redbird/issues/27

Comment: @Adi - did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: I haven't @blueren, try checking https://www.npmjs.com/package/hotel